# Setting a variable whose value depends on another variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

i have a text file **variables.txt** where i store my variables

> host=/srv/www/vhosts/hosting
>
> index=**$host**/index.php

as you see the second variables depends on the first one.

i also have a script file to load these variables

```
f=~/variables.txt
for line in $(cat $f)
do
export $line
done
```

when i execute the script file, my first variable gets loaded, while the second doesn't:

```
bash: $host/index.php: No such file or directory
```

it's because after loading the first variable **host**, it doesn't remember its value to use for setting the second variable **index**.

So how to solve this problem? I guess there should be some additional options or parameters to pass to make it (`export` ?) remember the set variable value in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary thing to note is that you probably don't need to export these variables; that necessity is reserved **only** when when a subprocess is querying its inherited environment for a variable. Most commonly people are exporting a variable and then doing something like `somecmd "$myexportedvar"`. Your shell is expanding `$myexportedvar` before `somecmd` ever sees it.

If you really do need to export these for a subprocess to pull from its environment:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == *=* && $line != #* ]]; then
    IFS== read -r var val <<<"$line"
    printf -v "$var" '%s' "$val"
    export "$var"
  fi
done < "$HOME/variables.txt"
```

this loop checks that the line is an assignment (kinda) and that the first character is not a comment hash. makes the effort a little more robust, but just barely. see the two options below instead, for handling this more carefully.

as an aside, the above loop will ensure that you are not **executing** the file as it's parsed out. `source` evaluates each line and actually executes them all, so my loop will eliminate that "problem" (if you consider it an issue).

Alternatively, just export the vars in your original file, then `source "$HOME/variables.txt"` and the work is already done.

you may want to just use `set -a; . "$HOME"/variables.txt; set +a`. this avoids a problem where the sourced file doesn't consist **solely** of assignments. the parsing loop above can result in false-positives. read `help set` to understand what it's doing.

Also, [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 2):

you have a easier way to perform that.

```
cat vars
host=/srv/www/vhosts/hosting
index=$host/index.php
```

my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./vars
echo $host
echo $index
```

Execution

```
./printvars.sh
/srv/www/vhosts/hosting
/srv/www/vhosts/hosting/index.php
```

Basically the . ./vars executes the files and loads the variables.

Comment: i know, but my actual file is too big and filled up with variable definitions, that i want to **`export`** with a `for` loop. i don't want to write `export` command on each line in my variables.txt file and then to source it, i want to do it with `for` loop instead.

Comment: The command `sed 's/^/export /' vars` writes "export" at the beginning of each line in vars. This is unix, you're trying to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would also be to source the file and export everything within the "variables.txt" file. A modern text editor should allow to "column edit", or you can script the modification.

However, I managed to answer your question with this script :

```
#!/bin/sh

f=./variables.txt
source ${f}
for vname in $(cut -f1 -d'=' ${f})
do
    export ${vname}
done
```

The difference is that I source the variables.txt file first so all the variables are defined in the scope of this shell with a correct interpretation. Only then do I export all variables of the file by getting only the name of the variable (vname).

On a side note, you should protect your variables with ${}.

Comment: as an aside to your aside, one should only use curly braces for two things: disambiguation between a variable's name and other coinjoined text `"${var}string"`, and alternatively for [Parameter Expansions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) `"${name:-default}"`. "Protecting" variables is to be done with double-quotes. [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

```
. ./vars
while read line; do
    export $(printf "%s" "$line" | grep = | cut -d= -f 1)
done < vars
```

or just one

```
while read line; do
   eval export "$line"
done < vars
```